# anacron is given priority over cron

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, scheduling, anacron

An extract from the book [Linux-In-Action](https://www.manning.com/books/linux-in-action)

```
As you can see from the crontab file, anacron is given priority over cron.
```

the crontab file he is referring is - `/etc/crontab`

---

Consider the below scenario

My system boots at `15:00 pm`

below was the entry in `/etc/anacrontab` file

```
1    10    myBackupJob_anacron    /home/farhanshirgill/Desktop/scripts/shellscript.sh
```

This command runs the `shellscript.sh` script no more than once a day, `10 minutes` after system boot. The job identifier is `myBackupJob_anacron`, and a log file of that name with job status information will be saved to the `/var/spool/anacron/` directory.

the `shellscript.sh` is kept simple and is responsible to create a file

```
#!/bin/sh
touch /home/farhanshirgill/Desktop/scripts/fileA.txt
```

After `10` mins at `15:10 pm`, i can see the file `fileA.txt` created in `/home/farhanshirgill/Desktop/scripts/`. Everything is okay up to this point of time.

---

In the *user* specific `crontab` file which is edited with `crontab -e`, the below entry was made

```
20 15 * * 0 touch /home/farhanshirgill/Desktop/scripts/fileB.txt
```

As seen, this should create the file `fileB.txt` at `15:20 pm`.

---

An entry was also made in `/etc/crontab` file like below

```
25 15 * * 0   farhanshirgill touch /home/farhanshirgill/Desktop/scripts/fileC.txt
```

As seen, this should create the file `fileC.txt` at `15:25 pm`.

---

The files(`fileB` & `fileC`) which were intended to be created with crontab(system & user ones) don't get created.

Does the entry in `/etc/anacrontab` have to do with this behavior. Please advise.

Comment: I can't tell why your last two files don't get created, but `anacron` does not disable the use of `cron`. Are you getting errors mailed to you by the cron daemon, or can you investigate the cron log to see whether it says something interesting?

Comment: Your `crontab` entry will only run once per week - on Sunday - that being a result of your trailing `0`. Were you aware of that? See [crontab guru](https://crontab.guru/#25_15_*_*_0)

Comment: My bad!. 0 is Sunday and its Monday here. Hence it has to be 1 and not 0, for user and system crontabs cron expression. I am late to comment but I had seen my mistake moments after putting the question.